# Echoing Javascript htmlspecialchars from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

im storing javascript code (google analytic js code) in a php variable using htmlspecialchars to escape the single quotes.
the problem is when im outputing the javascript to html page, the javascript printed as text

this from setting.php and will save to config.php

```
$analyticcode = htmlspecialchars("'.$_POST['analytic'].'");
```

config.php

```
$analyticcode = htmlspecialchars("
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-1111111-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>");
```

and this is the html from echo output

```
"\r\n&lt;script&gt;\r\n  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){\r\n  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),\r\n  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)\r\n  })(window,document,'script','https:\/\/www.google-analytics.com\/analytics.js','ga');\r\n  ga('create', 'UA-111111-1', 'auto');\r\n  ga('send', 'pageview');\r\n&lt;\/script&gt;"
```

please show me the correct way echoing this to html, 
thank you

Comment: Simple don't use htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 1):

Simply not use htmlspecialchars(). But just a string.

Example source code: https://hastebin.com/elaloxiqow.xml

Example result: http://kironweb123.000webhostapp.com/test.php

```
$analyticcode = "
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-1111111-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>";
```

I hope this is what you mean.

EDIT: According to your code http://hastebin.com/ukibebijav.xml it may work if you use  in index.php

Comment: it doesnt work on my page, im using $_POST to get the code from <text area> then save it to php as variable

Comment: You mean, the value of <text area> is that "
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-1111111-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>"?

Comment: yes, this javascript taken from text area and save to such as config php file

Comment: maybe then instead of htmlspecialchars() do htmlspecialchars_decode()?